# Gnome Disks utility freezing

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, gnome, mount, gnome-disk-utility

I recently mounted a new FAT32 HDD to my desktop (Ubuntu 18.04). After initially partitioning the drive I wanted to partition a larger space but realized that my GNOME disks management utility window is frozen when it loads and does not allow me to use any of the options or diagnostics without freezing. [Output of `fdisk -l` on mounted drive can be viewed below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSYs1.png). Although probably irrelevant, I also [added an image of the disk management window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wQhs.png). The freezing occurs once I try to resize the window or press any menu option. Also I am unable to check on the 2TB drive. Hopefully I can get some leads on how to fix this issue, Thanks.

[UPDATE] This problem actually is not local to just the gnome-disks utility but to any gnome related window. My files window and help center window also freeze.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs, if you pleased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*FAT32 max partition size - 2TB*  says https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/fat32-partition-size-limit.html

FAT32 is not recommended for use with large drives, since Ubuntu can easily and reliably access NTFS partitions. If al all possible, I'd suggest making that drive NTFS is sharing drives with Windows is your concern.

If Windows is not in use, [ext4](https://kernelnewbies.org/Ext4) is the popular choice for Ubuntu since it's faster than NTFS but has the journaling which protects you against power failure during a write operation

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I can reformat and see how that works. I am not concerned with sharing the drives though since I already wiped Windows from my desktop.

Comment: In which case, ext4 is the popular choice for Ubuntu since it's faster than NTFS but has the journalling which protects you against power failure during a write operation.

Comment: Awesome! Will make the change after I backup my files on the current disk. Thanks for the help!